# How do I get autotest to properly inflect singular models and plural controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tdd

Just as an example, if I have a `Book` model and a `BooksController`, autotest, part of the ZenTest suite will pick up the association between the two and load `test/unit/book_test.rb` and `test/functional/books_controller_test.rb` into the test suite. On the other hand, if I have a `Story` model and a `StoriesController`, autotest refuse to "notice" the `test/functional/stories_controller_test.rb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what was going on, and it had *nothing* to do with pluralization after all.

It had *everything* to do with the word "*stories*" which can be a special directory for one of the testing libraries (RSpec? Cucumber? I forget) So it was listed in my ~/.autotest config file as an exception! I'm not sure when I cut and pasted the snippet into the file, probably when I was first getting starting with ZenTest and didn't know what I was really doing.

```
Autotest.add_hook :initialize do |at|
  %w{... stories ...}.each {|exception|at.add_exception(exception)}
end
```

Adding a trailing slash ("stories/") restored the test and removed the brick marks from my forehead.

So I guess the lesson learned is: check for stray configuration files when debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately ZenTest isn't a rails plugin, so it doesn't benefit from ActiveSupport's pluralize method. Therefore it uses simple regular expressions to match the filenames. Have a look at ZenTest/autotest/rails.rb to see a list of the existing mappings for Rails.

At the end you have two options:

- (monkey) patch your own mapping rule
- forget about pluralization

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can override the mappings in your `.autotest` file.  Either in your home directory or at the root of the project.  You could `require 'active_support'` there to get `String#pluralize` and `String#singularize`.

Borrow the code from the rspec-rails plugin in [`lib/autotest/rails_rspec.rb`](http://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec-rails/blob/ba8c3eb84eacb8e9bc449c224cb57deebb7576f6/lib/autotest/rails_rspec.rb), it already seems to do the singular/plural magic with ActiveSupport.  You'll probably need to yank out the RSpec specific assumptions from there, though.